# PHP generated JS not running on IE7+

Tags: php, javascript, header, content-type

I've been playing around with JS generated in PHP and so far i've had no luck with IE. Other browsers like Firefox and Chrome successfully parse and execute the JS code.

For example this page

http://crusthq.com/projects/CrustTalk/

Loads this javascript

http://crusthq.com/projects/CrustTalk/_js/?page=demo

I tried sending the following headers in the PHP script http://crusthq.com/projects/CrustTalk/_js/

`Content-Type: text/javascript` , `Content-Type: application/x-javascript` , `Content-Type: application/javascript`

with no luck. Does anyone has any idea why IE is not parsing and executing the JS code?

Comment: It looks like the output is being minified.  Does the same error happen without the minified output?

Comment: The JS in the first link, is it supposed to do anything on that page?

Comment: @waitinforatrain when the JS runs successfully the animated loading overlay in the comment box disappears.

Comment: @Charles i tried outputting the raw code and no luck still

Answer (score 0):

I used [this instance of the Google Closure Compiler Service](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) to attempt to pretty-print your Javascript.

It failed with this error:

> **Number of errors: 1**
>
> JSC_TRAILING_COMMA: Parse error. Internet Explorer has a non-standard intepretation of trailing commas. Arrays will have the wrong length and objects will not parse at all. at line 190 character 183 in ?page=demo
>
> ```
> ...ully",delay:4,clear:false,method:"append",xButton:true,onClose:function(){},}
>                                                                               ^
> ```

That stray comma is probably where things are going wrong.

Comment: The code is 1,500 lines and 55k once pretty-printed.  I would suggest breaking it up into smaller chunks.  You've got five closures that look like they might be jQuery plugins, a call to getJSON in the middle and a few functions at the end.  With that much code and IE7's horrible dev tools, this might be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for your input Charles. The point of using PHP is to merge different JS files into one script. I'll just go back to including each JS file separate as I always had.